# How Do One Calculate Mean and Variance of a Vector with with Just A Function

Tags: r, mean, variance

I want a function to calculate the mean and variance of a vector at the same time (with a vector output) such that if I only want the value of the mean or only that of the variance I will only subset it with a `$` sign.

```
x <- function(n, a, b, mean, sd){
  meann = mean(truncnorm::rtruncnorm(n, a, b, mean, sd))
  std = sd(truncnorm::rtruncnorm(n, a, b, mean, sd))
  return(c(meann, std))
}
x(n=100, a = -1, b = 1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

If I want mean I will write `x$meann` and if I need standard deviation I will write `x$std`

Comment: `return(list(meann = meann, std = std))` will give you a named output.

Comment: Note that `meann = ` and `std = ` generate 2 different sample populations.  Better to initially generate a single sample population and take the mean and std from that.  You may also consider setting a seed in the function if it would support your output objective.